# How to detect if postgres connection goes down dynamically in pg npm (postgres package)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, npm, pg

I am trying to find connection status frequently in postgres pg npm package for my nodejs project

I can find the connection is active using the below event,

```
pool.on('connect', pool => {
  console.error('<------------------------connected------------------------>')
});
```

but like the above event i need something like

```
pool.on('disconnect', pool => {
  console.error('<------------------------disconnected------------------------>')
});
```

I have checked the events in the core link https://node-postgres.com/api/pool but no luck.
Kindly help me how to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
pool.on('error', (err: Error, client: Client) => void) => void
```

It is what you are looking for. Already mentioned in your link

Comment: no. i tried it but its not triggered when i manually close the postgres connection

Comment: Why do you need an event then. You can do cleanup/anything else in callback 
`pool.end(() => {
  console.log('pool has ended')
doSomething();
})`

Comment: no.. what i expect If i do the following it should trigger.,
1. I run the npm start 
2. Once postgres connected successfully I close my VPN(which connection have my postgres db in remote)
3. After disconnect the VPN I need notification